# How can I get a dynamic multidimensional string array in c#?

Tags: c#, string, list, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a dynamic multidimensional list. But without success.

I want to have a "Key" with dynamic "Values".

For example:

I want to add this to the list:

```
Key: "ABC", Value: (10.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f, 90.0f)

Key: "MVG", Value: (35.0f, 35.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f)

Key: "ABC", Value: (200.0f, 500.0f, 70.0f, 0.0f)
```

etc.

Look at "ABC". I don't want to create a new "ABC" key. The values should be added to the "ABC" key.

Like this:

"ABC" -> 10.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f, 90.0f -> 200.0f, 500.0f, 70.0f, 0.0f

"MVG" -> 35.0f, 35.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f

My List code looks like this:

```
List<string[,,] > mainList = new List<string[,,,]>();
```

It's not working. Why?

Comment: The values appear to be a list of floats. Do you *really* want to store them as strings?

Comment: I want to store the keys as strings, and the values as floats. I don't know how to do that. So I made the floats as strings.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, List<List<float>>>` maybe: a dictionary with a string key, containing a list of lists of floats

Answer (score 0):

This cant work:

```
List<string[,,] > mainList = new List<string[,,,]>();
```

**,,** and **,,,**

The types don´t match

```
List<string[, , ,]> xxx = new List<string[, , ,]>();
```

is ok.

But what you are actually search for is a jagged Array:

```
List<string[][][]> yyy = new List<string[][][]>();
```

Good luck with keeping the dimensions together ...

Comment: Ok. No error. What is with the rest. Is that not possible?

Comment: also ok, but you asked for dynamic multidimensional array, so I gave this answer.

Comment: But, jagged array is not dynamic. I must give the size.

Comment: yes and no: you can define it without dimensions, and assign it from e.g. a list: myJaggedArry[i1][i2] = yourList.ToArray()

Comment: If you are working with large lists, so be aware that you also should initialize the list with a size, to avoid (hidden) memory allocations (each time the list is to small there is some copy work happening behind the scene to create a new list and transfer the data)